# "Linker command failed..." when compiling a C++ program with header files on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, linker

I'm on an M1 Mac, using Visual Studio Code with clang++ and writing with C++17 library. I'm simply trying to compile a C++ program on Mac, using headers. Whenever I do, I'm left with the clang error of "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)".

Here's my code:
**main.cpp**

```
#include "test.h"

int main() 
{
    test obj = test();

    obj.Hello();

    return 0;
}
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include "test.h"

void test::Hello()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
}
```

**test.h**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class test
{
    public:
    explicit test();

    void Hello();
};
```

Here's the compile command:
`clang++ -std=c++17 main.cpp test.cpp -o testFile`

Here's the response:

ld: Undefined symbols:
test::test(), referenced from:
_main in main-40382b.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I've tried both clang++ and g++ compilation, as well as compiling within Visual Studio Code. Within VSC, I've selected the compilerPath and set the includePath as well as done a bunch of different variations of my compiler command in terminal. Just can't get past the linker command error.

Comment: Where is the definition of the `test` constructor?

Comment: `explicit test();` you promised to implement `test::test()` . I don't see that so if this is your exact code, your linker is telling you about breaking your promise.

Comment: Never break a promise with the compiler. It is utterly unforgiving. Make it mad enough and it may even send assassin robots back in time to kill your parents.